# Event handler not working in external JS file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This works: (Keeping it all in one file)

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
    //content-wrapper --> ajax loaded
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
            var a_row_id = 0;
            $('body').on('click', '.ready-create-rename-row', function() {
                a_row_id = $(this).data('row-id');
                console.log('Attempting to rename row ' + a_row_id);
            });
        });
    </script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't: I'm not getting any errors, but the event handler doesn't fire; console stays empty

```
<html><head></head>
    <body>
    <!-- content-wrapper -- ajax loaded -->        
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/func_rows.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       //Some code in document.ready
    </script>      
    </body>
</html>
```

func_rows.js:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    var a_row_id = 0;
    $('body').on('click', '.ready-create-rename-row', function() {
        a_row_id = $(this).data('row-id');
        console.log('Attempting to rename row ' + a_row_id);
    });
    //Other events here get fired however
});
```

Ajax loaded content:

```
<div class="row-options">
    <button type="button" class="flat circle ready-create-rename-row" 
                 data-row-id=<?php echo $r->id; ?>
                 data-label-id='row_rename_<?php echo $r->id; ?>' 
                 data-toggle="modal" 
                 data-target="#rename-row-modal">
                 <i class="mdi mdi-pencil"></i>
    </button>
</div>

<!-- Rename Row Confirmation Modal -->
<div id="rename-row-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog plain-material-dialog confirmation">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content plain-material-content">
        <div class="modal-body plain-material-body">
                Rename Row
        <div class="material-input-group stretched">
                    <label>Row name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="create-new-row-name" required>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer plain-material-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flat" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flat" id="create-rename-row">rename</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's confusing me is that the other event handlers in `ajaxComplete` in `func_rows.js` get fired even when they're bound to ajax-loaded elements. What I'm expecting is that when you click on the button with `.ready-create-rename-row` a message will pop up in the console, but nothing happens. But when I put the event handler in the same html file (serving as the template), it works.

Comment: Why bother using `$.ajaxComplete()` when you're attaching delegated event handlers anyway? All this will do is duplicate the handlers on successive requests anyway

Comment: I thought I needed it for ajax-loaded content. So it's okay to remove it?

Comment: Absolutely fine. Just use the delegated event handler by itself

Comment: is your path to the file correct.

Comment: @Suchitkumar yes. like i've said, there are other event handlers in `ajaxComplete` that for some reason get fired. When I transfer that event handler for `.ready-create-rename-row` to the base file or the file where the scripts get loaded, it works. But when it's in the external js file, it doesn't get fired.I'm not sure what I'm missing out on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the culprit is another method in the `ajaxComplete` handler:

```
$('body').off().on('click', '.rename-row' function()
{
   //stuff

    $.ajax({
     //Stuff
    });
 });
```

The `.off()` was basically disabling all the events that came before it, so I had to put it at the top and just changed the `'body'` to the class `.rename-row'` to be much safer.